# Flag and compare data in Python

Tags: python

I have set of data where the particular column FILENAME is like `Apr14WSJ_CNYR_NOEMAIL_CAP_TM_20140728.txt`. So I am searching the the string for `_NOEMAIL_` as in unix script.This below script sorts the string on basis of wether it has N0EMAIL or not and then I again do if with it.

```
echo $FILENAME | grep "_NOEMAIL_"
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
then
    FILEEMAIL_FLG="N"
else
    FILEEMAIL_FLG="Y"
fi
```

I tried to write same for python.

```
 N0_EMAIL = str
 y = NO_EMAIL
 x = str(row['FILENAME']
 if y in x:
    print ('true')
 else:
    print ('false')
```

I cant get the result as I wanted. please let me know how I can get it.

Comment: and what output do you get? I am a bit confused by your code. You assign str (which is function!) to N0_EMAIL (with zero after N), then assign NO_EMAIL (with uppercase o after N) to y. Can you explain, please?

Comment: `str` is a builtin function ... try `NO_EMAIL="_NOEMAIL_"` instead

Comment: my python code is faulty ,will like to have a new diff approach.

Comment: If you just want to check for a substring, `if "bar" in "foobarbaz": pass` is enough.

Comment: I am new into python ,what i got from pass it is placeholder which allows you to pass some methods even you dnt want to.I am confused, how i can implement the program with pass.I guess it will be easier for me and i can do some nested if loop.

Comment: import csv
    csv.register_dialect('piper', delimiter='|',                                                                                  quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)with open('temp1.txt','rb') as csvfile:
    for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect='piper'):
        abc = str(row['FILENAME'])
        for letter in abc:
            if letter == '_NOEMAIL_':
                print 'it is dm:',letter
            break
        else:
            print 'bad word'